If $\mathsf{GCH}$ fails on a measure one set must it fail at $\kappa$?
Suppose $U$ is a normal measure on $\kappa$. It is well known that if $\{\alpha<\kappa:2^\alpha=\alpha^+\}\in U$ then $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$.
Question: does $\{\alpha<\kappa:2^\alpha=\alpha^{++}\}\in U$ imply $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$?
It certainly implies $2^\kappa=\kappa^{++}$ in the ultrapower $M=\mathrm{Ult}(V,U)$, but I'm struggling to translate that to $V$. On the opposite direction, I wonder if something like lottery iteration can provide a counterexample.

No. It doesn't mean that.
Suppose that $U$ was such measure and force with $\operatorname{Col}(\kappa^+, 2^\kappa)$. Since the forcing is $\kappa^+$-closed we are not adding subsets of size $\kappa$ to the universe, so $U$ is still a normal measure and it's still true that $\{\alpha<\kappa\mid 2^\alpha=\alpha^{++}\}\in U$, but in that model $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$.

Thanks, that should have been obvious...A follow up question: what's the consistency strength of ${\alpha<\kappa\mid 2^\alpha=\alpha^{++}}\in U$?

Not sure, but presumably forcing with an Easton support iteration of $\operatorname{Add}(\alpha,\alpha^{++})$ for inaccessible $\alpha<\kappa$ over a model of $\sf ZFC$ and then adding "just enough generics" for $\kappa$ itself would work. But I'm not sure how sound that approach might be.
